# login in flex and java using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-flex, fingerprint

I have problem with my login application in java and flex. we use fingerprint login. the system waits for 60 seconds for any fingerprint input from the user. After that it automatically goes out of the page. The user also has text password option on that page. When user clicks on that option, control goes to some other page. But the problem is whenver user click on text password option, he is redirected but the thread of 60 seconds keep running. Can any one help me how to stop that thread. Here is my code. I am using blocking queue concept to get out of the input screen by inputting some dummy value of one bit.

```
private void interruptCaptureProcess() {
    System.out.println("Interrupting Capture Process.");
    ExactScheduledRunnable fingerScanInterruptThread = new ExactScheduledRunnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                if (capture != null) 
                {
                    DPFPSampleFactoryImpl test = new DPFPSampleFactoryImpl();
                    samples.put(test.createSample(new byte[1]));
                    capture.stopCapture();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                LOGGER.error("interruptCaptureProcess", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    timeOutScheduler.schedule(fingerScanInterruptThread, getTimeOutValue(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

/**
 * Scans and Verifies the user finger print by matching it with the previous registered template for the user.
 * 
 * @param userVO is the user value object which has to be verified.
 * @return the acknowledgment string according to result for operation performed.
 * @throws UserServiceException when there is an error in case of getting user record.
 */
public String verifyUserFingerPrint(Long userId) throws LoginServiceException {
    System.out.println("Performing fingerprint verification...\n");
    interruptCaptureProcess();
    UserVO userVO = null;
    try {

        userVO = new UserService().findUserById(userId, true);
        if (userVO != null) {

            stopCaptureProcess();
            DPFPSample sample = getSample(selectReader(), "Scan your finger\n");
            timeOutScheduler.shutdownNow();
            if (sample.serialize().length == 1) {
                System.out.println("Coming in code");
                return null;
            } else if (sample.serialize().length == 2) {
                System.out.println("Capturing Process has been Timed-Out");
                return TIMEOUT;
            }

            if (sample == null)
                throw new UserServiceException("Error in scanning finger");

            DPFPFeatureExtraction featureExtractor = DPFPGlobal.getFeatureExtractionFactory()
                .createFeatureExtraction();
            DPFPFeatureSet featureSet = featureExtractor.createFeatureSet(sample,
                DPFPDataPurpose.DATA_PURPOSE_VERIFICATION);
            DPFPVerification matcher = DPFPGlobal.getVerificationFactory().createVerification();
            matcher.setFARRequested(DPFPVerification.MEDIUM_SECURITY_FAR);

            byte[] tempByte = userVO.getFingerPrint();
            DPFPTemplateFactory facotory = new DPFPTemplateFactoryImpl();
            for (DPFPFingerIndex finger : DPFPFingerIndex.values()) {
                DPFPTemplate template = facotory.createTemplate(tempByte);
                if (template != null) {
                    DPFPVerificationResult result = matcher.verify(featureSet, template);
                    // Fix of enh#1029
                    Map<ScriptRxConfigType, Map<ScriptRxConfigName, String>> scriptRxConfigMap = ScriptRxConfigMapSingleton
                        .getInstance().getScriptRxConfigMap();
                    Map<ScriptRxConfigName, String> fingerPrintPropertiesMap = scriptRxConfigMap
                        .get(ScriptRxConfigType.FINGERPRINT);
                    String fingerPrintDemoMode = fingerPrintPropertiesMap.get(ScriptRxConfigName.DEMOMODE);
                    if (fingerPrintDemoMode != null && fingerPrintDemoMode.equalsIgnoreCase("DemoEnabled")) {
                        return "LOGS_MSG_101";
                    }
                    // End of fix of enh#1029
                    if (result.isVerified()) {
                        System.out.println("Matching finger: %s, FAR achieved: %g.\n" + fingerName(finger)
                            + (double) result.getFalseAcceptRate() / DPFPVerification.PROBABILITY_ONE);
                        return "LOGS_MSG_101";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException iob) {
        LOGGER.error("verifyUserFingerPrint", iob);
        throw new LoginServiceException("LOGS_ERR_101", iob);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        LOGGER.error("verifyUserFingerPrint", exp);
        System.out.println("Failed to perform verification.");
        throw new LoginServiceException("LOGS_ERR_105", exp);
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        LOGGER.error("verifyUserFingerPrint", th);
        throw new LoginServiceException("LOGS_ERR_106", th.getMessage(), th);
    }
    System.out.println("No matching fingers found for \"%s\".\n" + userVO.getFirstName().toUpperCase());
    throw new LoginServiceException("LOGS_ERR_107", null);
}


/* finger scanning process
 */
private void stopCaptureProcess() {
    ExactScheduledRunnable fingerScanInterruptThread = new ExactScheduledRunnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                DPFPSampleFactoryImpl test = new DPFPSampleFactoryImpl();
                samples.put(test.createSample(new byte[2]));
                capture.stopCapture();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    timeOutScheduler.schedule(fingerScanInterruptThread, getTimeOutValue(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

/**
 * API will get the value for the finger scanner time out configuration(Default will be 60 seconds)
 */
private long getTimeOutValue() {
    long waitTime = 60;
    String configValue = ScriptRxSingleton.getInstance().getConfigurationValue(ConfigType.Security,
        ConfigName.FingerprintTimeout);
    try {
        waitTime = Long.valueOf(configValue);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        LOGGER.debug("Configuration value is not a number for FingerTimeOut", e);
    }
    return waitTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stopping blocking tasks in Java is a complicated topic, and requires cooperation between the blocking code and the code that wants to unblock it. The most common way in Java is to interrupt the thread that is blocking, which works if the code that is blocking and the code around it understands interruption. If that's not the case you're out of luck. Here's an answer that explains one way to interrupt a thread that is blocking in an `Executor`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9281038/1109