# Is it possible to interrupt a specific thread of an ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

If I have an `ExecutorService` to which I feed Runnable tasks, can I select one and interrupt it?
I know I can cancel the Future returned (also mentioned [Here: how-to-interrupt-executors-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280846/how-to-interrupt-executors-thread)), but how can I raise an `InterruptedException`. Cancel doesn't seem to do it (event though it should by looking at the sources, maybe the OSX implementation differs). At least this snippet doesn't print 'it!' Maybe I'm misunderstaning something and it's not the custom runnable that gets the exception?

```
public class ITTest {
static class Sth {
    public void useless() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}

static class Runner implements Runnable {
    Sth f;
    public Runner(Sth f) {
        super();
        this.f = f;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            f.useless();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("it!");
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Sth f = new Sth();
    Future<?> lo = es.submit(new Runner(f));
    lo.cancel(true); 
    es.shutdown();
}
```

}

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to know how the `ExecutorService` is arranging its threads.  How would you be able to cancel a specific one of them?

Comment: You've got the point, but if I have some kind of a producer consumer pattern, where I should be able to stop a non-responive thread by interruption, this way I can't. Or should I design it so that Future.cancel is eligible for the cancellation?

Comment: Yes, @zeller, design it for use with `Future.cancel()`. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The right thing to do here is to cancel the `Future`.  The issue is that this will not necessarily cause an `InterruptedException`.

If the job has yet to run then it will be removed from the runnable queue -- I think this is your problem here.  If the job has already finished then it won't do anything (of course).  If it is still running then it will *interrupt the thread*.

Interrupting a thread will only cause `sleep()`, `wait()`, and some other methods to throw `InterruptedException`.  You will also need test to see if the thread has been interrupted with:

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
```

Also, it is a good pattern to re-set the interrupt flag if you catch `InterruptedException`:

```
try {
   Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // this is a good pattern otherwise the interrupt bit is cleared by the catch
   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   ...
}
```

In your code, I would try putting a sleep *before* you call `lo.cancel(true)`.  It may be that you are canceling the future *before* it gets a chance to execute.

Comment: ... and the InterruptedExceptions must be caught by whatever is calling sleep() or wait(), which means that it might not get to your code. In general, calling Thread.interrupt() doesn't automatically halt execution of the thread. It only has an effect if the executing code is checking the interrupt flag. For this reason it's often very difficult to retrofit existing code to respond to interrupts.

Comment: I'd probably advise not interrupting a worker thread managed by a `ThreadPoolExecutor` considering the Oracle JDK 7 implementation uses interrupts internally.