# Is there anything wrong with my ExecutorService code?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

So I've written a block of code that will submit an array of objects through a task handler, I had an instance come up where the program crashed and did not close properly... Will this code do what I'm thinking it should?

In my mind the following code should take an object, pass it to a handler, and then wait until a maximum of 30s has passed, and if that thread hasn't completed, kill it.   Right?

```
 //Iterate through the array to submit them into individual running threads.
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
    List<Future<?>> taskList = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
        Future<?> task = threadPool.submit(new ThreadHandler(objectArray[i], i));
        taskList.add(task);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

    //Event handler to kill any threads that are running for more than 30 seconds (most threads should only need .25 - 1 second to complete.
    for(Future future : taskList){
        try{
            future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }catch(CancellationException cx){ System.err.println("Cancellation Exception: "); cx.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ExecutionException ex){ System.err.println("Execution Exception: ");ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch(InterruptedException ix){ System.err.println("Interrupted Exception: ");ix.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    threadPool.shutdown(); // SHUT. DOWN. EVERYTHING.
```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is a more appropriate place for these kinds of questions.

Comment: I would remove the sleep for 500 ms. Just add all the tasks at once.  Without the exact error message, it hard to know what went wrong or even if it has anything to do with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Event handler to kill any threads that are running for more than 
//30 seconds (most threads should only need .25 - 1 second to complete.
```

No it won't, you're just not waiting for them to finish anymore. Use `cancel` to kill it for good:

```
for(Future future : taskList){
    try{
        future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }catch(TimeoutException ex) {
        future.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Also you should make sure the executor finished after calling `shutdown`:

```
threadPool.shutdown();
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Answer (score 2):

It will throw `TimeoutException` if work is not completed in 30 Seconds. You need to use [Future.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) in order to cancel the thread. It will interrupt running thread represented by Future.

Answer (score 2):

> the program crashed and did not close properly

From comments it seems like the program *hung* instead of crashed.  Please use the correct terms to describe problems in the future.  It seems like some sort of remote web request did not finish. Make sure that you set IO timeouts on all http-client and other connections if possible.  `thread.interrupt()` will most likely *not* stop a web request unless it is using NIO interruptible channels.

For example:

```
HttpClientParams params = new HttpClientParams();
params.setSoTimeout(socketTimeoutMillis);
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(params);
```

> In my mind the following code should take an object, pass it to a handler, and then wait until a maximum of 30s has passed, and if that thread hasn't completed, kill it. Right?

Your code doesn't quite do that.

- You should call `threadPool.shutdown()` just after you've submitted your last task to it.  The thread-pool stops accepting new tasks but the submitted tasks continue to run.
- If you want to "kill" any tasks that have been running for more than 30 seconds, you should use `threadPool.shutdownNow()` which will actually interrupt the jobs that are still running in the `threadPool`.  You can also call the individual tasks with `future.cancel()` as others have recommended when the `get()` times out.
- Note that to have the interrupt work, your `ThreadHandler` will have to be checking `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` to be able to see the interrupt.  Interrupting also causes sleep, wait, and other methods to throw `InterruptedException`.  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060279/is-it-possible-to-interrupt-a-specific-thread-of-an-executorservice/12060317#12060317) for more details.

Comment: I have no more information on what caused it to crash, it timestamped the log then continued to run for a few days.

Comment: Careful about words like "crash".  You talking about an exception or a JVM fault and exit @Damien.Bell?

Comment: Here's what I know.   At some point the batch that runs my program was called on 9/28/2012, at around 10:30am UMT.   At this time, the program ran to the point where it timestamps (about 10 LOC into main) and then failed somewhere in the code above.   It wrote nothing to the log.   During this process java.exe remained running causing future jobs to fail until I killed the java.exe process this morning when I noticed that data was outdated.  I have no other info on the failure.  I'm thinking some kind of web-get may have failed (Jsoup or HttpClient).

Comment: So perhaps "Hung" may have been the better word, as it doesn't seemed to have exited in 3-4 days.

Comment: Yeah, this happens a lot @Damien.Bell.  You should make sure, if possible, that all of your web requests have IO timeouts set on them.  Interrupt doesn't "kill" the thread as I mentioned.  It just interrupts certain interruptible methods/classes.

Comment: I've added an example of http client timeouts @Damien.Bell.