# How to get the interrupted status of a terminated Java Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception, thread-state

I'm trying to determine if a Java Thread was `interrupted` or not at the time that it terminated.  So far the answer seems to be "no"...

Right before falling off the end of `run()` we can see `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` is `true`.

But after `join()`ing the target thread we always get `false`:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ThreadDeadInterruptStateTest {
    @Test public void test() {
        Thread a = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } finally {
                    // 2x to show that check doesn't reset status
                    assertTrue("Interrupt status from a 1: ",  // pass
                            Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                    assertTrue("Interrupt status from a 2: ",  // pass
                            Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                }
            }});
        a.start();
        a.interrupt();
        try {
            a.join();
            assertEquals("Thread state", a.getState(),
                    Thread.State.TERMINATED);  // pass
            assertTrue("Interrupt status after join: ",
                    a.isInterrupted());  // Still FAILs :-(
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadDeadInterruptStateTest().test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed the typo.  Still busted.

Comment: It seems like it is the `join` call which clears the status: http://ideone.com/2s0x6H. I can't see where that behaviour is documented, though.

Comment: Voted to reopen, but I'd reclose immediately as a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401947/methods-that-clear-the-thread-interrupt-flag

Comment: @AndyTurner Your search-fu is strong

Answer (score 4):

You're checking the wrong thread's status:

```
Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
```

is the status of the main thread, because you execute it directly inside the `test` method. You didn't interrupt this one, you interrupted `a`. So, check `a`'s status:

```
a.isInterrupted()
```

Comment: After fixing the typo (thanks!) we still have the same problem.  `a.isInterrupted()` is still false after the join!?!?!